# Validate data in renderPartial in Yii

Tags: yii

I just created this a renderPartial():

renderPartial('/users/_form', array('model'=>new Users), true, true); ?>

the problem that the data entered doesn't validated.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Your model is always "new Users". So you are not validating anithing.

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear from your question exactly WHEN you want to validate.

If on client side you need something like this:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'your-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
  'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
  ), 
)); ?>
```

Plus this in your controller in the post action:
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
Along with a controller method like:

```
/** 
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param CModel the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
  if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='saferides-registered-form')
  {   
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
  }   
}
```

If you only want to validate on post, something like this as part of your controller action that handles the post:

```
if ( $model->validate() && $model-save() )
{
  ..redirect to your view
}
```

Also consult the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model)